# ERROR: ld.so: object LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored

Tags: linux, bash

I am using ubuntu 12.04. Every time I start my bash terminal and every time when I finish typing a command(and press enter) , I get this message:

> ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/liblunar-calendar-preload.so' from
>   LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

It is weird.
So what is the environment variable LD_PRELOAD used for? And what is the going on behind the scene?

Thanks.

Comment: Some libraries are only loaded when they are used. I think with the LD_PRELOAD variable you can try to load a library whether you use it or not before the program starts running.

Comment: @hetepeperfan And every time I enter a command, I get the message too. What should that be explained?

Comment: Are you using a custom built `bash`?

Comment: @devnull I am using the default bash. That is Application-> Accessory ->Terminal.

Comment: You have `LD_PRELOAD` defined somewhere (either in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` ...).  Say `unset LD_PRELOAD` and then issue a command; you won't see the error.

Comment: @devnull No. I can't find any LD_PRELOAD definition in files like ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, /etc/profile.

Comment: Does this give you an error? `unset LD_PRELOAD; ls`

Comment: @devnull Yes, I do not get the error message now.

Comment: @lulyon That suggests that `LD_PRELOAD` is being set somewhere.  And you need to get rid of it to get rid of the errors!

Comment: @devnull I am worried that without loading some library, It would cause other problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The linker takes some environment variables into account. one is `LD_PRELOAD`

from `man 8 ld-linux`:

```
LD_PRELOAD
          A whitespace-separated list of additional,  user-specified,  ELF
          shared  libraries  to  be loaded before all others.  This can be
          used  to  selectively  override  functions   in   other   shared
          libraries.   For  setuid/setgid  ELF binaries, only libraries in
          the standard search directories that are  also  setgid  will  be
          loaded.
```

Therefore the linker will try to load libraries listed in the `LD_PRELOAD` variable before others are loaded.

What could be the case that inside the variable is listed a library that can't be pre-loaded. look inside your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` environment where the `LD_PRELOAD` is set and remove that library from the variable.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to make sure that the library is loaded ***if and only if*** the program `lunar-calendar-gtk` is launched, you can apply this:

You set the environment variable per command by prefixing the command with it:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD="liblunar-calendar-preload.so" printenv "LD_PRELOAD"
liblunar-calendar-preload.so
$ printenv "LD_PRELOAD"
$
```

You can then choose to put this in a shell script and make `lunar-calendar-gtk` a symlink to this shell script, replaceing the original referencee. This effectively makes sure that the library is loaded everytime the original application is executed.

You will have to rename the original `lunar-calendar-gtk` to something else, which might not be too intriguing as it possibly may cause issues with uninstallation and upgrading. However, I found it useful with a former version of Skype.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the responses. I think I've solved the problem just now.

Since LD_PRELOAD is for setting some library proloaded, I check the library that ld preloads with LD_PRELOAD, one of which is "liblunar-calendar-preload.so", that is not existing in the path "/usr/lib/liblunar-calendar-preload.so", but I find a similar library "liblunar-calendar-preload-2.0.so", which is a difference version of the former one.

Then I guess maybe liblunar-calendar-preload.so was updated to a 2.0 version when the system updated, leaving LD_PRELOAD remain to be "/usr/lib/liblunar-calendar-preload.so". Thus the preload library name was not updated to the newest version.

To avoid changing environment variable, I create a symbolic link under the path "/usr/lib"

```
sudo ln -s liblunar-calendar-preload-2.0.so liblunar-calendar-preload.so
```

Then I restart bash, the error is gone.

Comment: But then for every program you start that library will be loaded, while changes are big, very, very big that the program will NOT need that library. Therefore you create additional workload for the pc when it is not necessary.

Comment: @hetepeperfan Thanks for pointing out that. But I do not think that is a problem, because the library is only loaded when the bash shell start, not before every program I start. the liblunar-calendar-preload.so is used by the program lunar-calendar-gtk. I do not think lunar-calendar-gtk will run smoothly without preloading the liblunar-calendar-preload.so.

Answer (score 5):

The solution that worked for me was using sudo vim and going into `/etc/ld.so.preload`

I then just removed the line

```
/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so
```

Then I just saved the file and everything worked without issues.

Answer (score 2):

It means the path you input caused an error. In your `LD_PRELOAD` command, modify the path like the error tips:

```
/usr/lib/liblunar-calendar-preload.so
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this type of error when I installed Citrix client on my Raspberry Pi. In short there is a file /etc/ld.so.preload. The library my system was complaining about was listed in that file. I commented it out with a # and system stopped complaining.

Answer (score -3):

When I executed the following command, everything became better.

```
unset LD_PRELOAD
```

Answer (score -5):

You can check **/etc/ld.so.preload** file content

I fix it by:

> echo "" > /etc/ld.so.preload

Comment: And with that, you have blindly removed all contents of that file.

Comment: dont do it! is very damageable!