# Fedora 33 openjdk 8 error showing on terminal

Tags: fedora

I am getting below error whenever I open the terminal. This began happening after upgrading Fedora Workstation 32 to 33.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.265.b01-1.fc32.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I still have OpenJDK 8 installed and even when uninstalled, above error keeps popping up making my terminal untidy

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723666/error-ld-so-object-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded-ignored) helped me to get a solution. I had the below the line in .bash_profile

./home/admin/Adempiere/postgresql/8.1.5/PGSQL.env

. I simply commented it out as below and my issue was solved. Read the above answer for the details of why this caused me issues. In my case, the program "Adempiere" had been uninstalled but it didn't remove this path which no longer existed.

#./home/admin/Adempiere/postgresql/8.1.5/PGSQL.env

If you get any error related to the above, review paths set in your .bash_profile
or /.bashrc , if you have a missing path; definitely this will throw this error